# Random Images in Ruby on rails 4 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, random

I am using this code to display random images for similar products in the same category the selected product is in.

```
 <div class="row container product-teaser">
   <h4 class="text-center teaser-text"> similar products to <%= @product.title %> : </h4>

     <% @products_rand.each do |product| %>
       <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3 center-block product-thumbs-product-view" >
          <%= link_to product_path (product) do %>
             <% if product.images.first %>
          <%= image_tag @product.images.first.image.url(:medium), :size => "100%x100%", class: "img-responsive center-block" %>
          <% end %>        
      <% end %>
      <h5 class="text-center"><%= link_to product.title, product, class: "text-center" %></h5>
  </div>
    <% end %>
 </div>
```

The problem is that the products in this `loop` are all displaying the image for the one selected product but the names and the link for the products are correct.

THis picture shows what I mean, the Customer have selected a product called ATLAS and similar products ( products from the same `category`) are displaying with the Atlas picture.

[image]

here is the `product_controller.rb`

```
 class ProductsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def show

  offset = rand(100)
  @meta_title = "Concept Store #{@product.title}"
  @meta_description = @product.description
  @products_rand = Product.where(category_id: @product.category_id).order("RANDOM()").limit(6)
 end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_product
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :price, :image, :category_id, :stock_quantity, :label_id, :query, :slug, images_attributes: [:image , :id , :_destroy])
end


end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
<%= image_tag @product.images.first.image.url(:medium), :size => "100%x100%", class: "img-responsive center-block" %>
```

Should be:

```
<%= image_tag product.images.first.image.url(:medium), :size => "100%x100%", class: "img-responsive center-block" %>
```

If you use `@product`, you are referencing the instance from your controller. If you use `product`, you are referencing the instance from your each loop.